# Python & SQLite: fetchone() and fetchall() and cursor control

Tags: python, sqlite

If cursor.execute('select * from users') returns a 4 row set, and then cursor.fetchone(), is there a way to re-position the cursor to the beginning of the returned results so that a subsequent cursor.fetchall() gives me all 4 rows?

Or do I need to the cursor.execute again, and then cursor.fetchall()?  This seems awkward.

I checked the Python docs and couldn't find something relevant.  What am I missing?

Comment: The C API has `sqlite3_stmt_reset`, but it does not appear that Python exposes this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite computes each result row on demand, so it is neither possible to go back to an earlier row, nor to determine how many following rows there will be.

The only way to go back is to re-execute the query. Alternatively, call `fetchall()` first, and then use the returned list instead of the cursor.